# Re-download Corrupted Part of ISO

Tags: linux, wget, kali-linux, iso, download

I have download an ISO file from one of the public FTP server. It took a lot of time to download the file because of my Internet Connection Issues. I used the wget command to download the ISO in Linux. I have paused my download many times because of the Connection issues.After completing my Download i extracted the files in the ISO and tried to install it in my Windows 8.1 OS. After reaching about 70% suddenly it started giving Error saying that "abcdefg.lkj" is corrupted.I ignored the first error and then after sometime it is giving me another error.I'm sure that there is no issue with the ISO in the FTP, many around the world have downloaded it and they say it is working properly.

Now i need a command or a solution so that i can download those corrupted part of the ISO and install it properly.

Comment: Did the download not show any errors while downloading? If at some point the transfer broke you could set up the download at that point without restarting from the beginning. I don't know the options for `wget` (if there are any) but the `curl` program has option `-C` to achieve that.

Comment: It's related to your download manager to used  up to 70%.

Answer (score 0):

FTP protocol is not intelligent enough for this, but check if the same iso file is available over `rsync` protocol.  rsync client will verify the integrity of your file against original on the server and download missing/corrupted parts.